# Display image from byte array in blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using blazor webassembly and I need to display an image that stored as byte array in the client side.

I tried

in C#:

```
imagesrc= Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
imageDataURL = string.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", imagesrc);
```

in markup:

```
<img src="@imageDataURL" />
```

but no image displayed just icon that no image.

is there any other way?

Comment: It should have kind-of worked. Any errors in the F12 console?

Comment: @HenkHolterman no, no errors in console

Comment: And when you use Inspect (F12, Elements), how does the <img> look?

Comment: @HenkHolterman is it matter if I'm displaying the image in the client side? the image stored as bytes no paths

Comment: Well, you can't show much on a server...

Comment: @HenkHolterman when inspect it it looks like this 

`<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,PHN2Z............(the bytes as base64)"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A jpg file has a standard header. So even with  different images I would expect the first few characters of the base64 to be the same.

When I convert a jpg to base64 it starts with `"/9j/4AAQ"`

So I think your data is not a (valid/complete) jpg file.

Comment: the image was svg before got its bytes and I used svg instead of jpg but still the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot I tried to get a jpeg image bytes now and displayed.

Answer (score 8):

I was curious which image format you specified instead of jpeg and like you said under @Henk answer it is `svg` as it starts with `PHN2Z...`

That doesn't mean you have to use some svg to jpeg converter, just adjust data uri type appropriately:

```cs
imageDataURL = string.Format("data:image/svg+xml;base64,{0}", imagesrc);
```

[Heres quick blazor playground which displays data uri for various image files](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/257kmy0p)

Comment: svg would be a lot smaller and faster than jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your code:

```
<img src="data:image;base64, @System.Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes) />
```

Where "imageBytes" is your byte[] image.